# mongodb ​nested array conditional update

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to update specific fields in multilevel array entries that match specific ids. One of of the changes has to based on a condition. I have managed to update the static value field correctly but I am not able to apply the conditional change.

the collection items contain a members array, who’s members contain an email_status array, matching the document id, member id, and email_status id, i need to update 2 fields in that specific email_status entry. The prevalent_status has to be set only if its current value matches a condition.

document:

```
{
    _id: ....,
    members: [
         { 
               _id: ....,
              email_statuses: [
                      {
                            _id: ....,
                           prevalent_status: 'SENDING',
                           statuses: {
                                 sent_at: ''
                           }
                      }
              ]
          }
     ]
}
```

Code that targets email_status proerly but doesn't handle the condition

```
db.collection.updateOne({
  "_id": parentID
},
{
$set: {
    "members.$[e1].email_status.$[e2].statuses.sent_at": "2023-05-22 16:00:00",
    "members.$[e1].email_status.$[e2].prevalent_status": {
        $cond: {
            if: {
                "$members.$[e1].email_status.$[e2].prevalent_status": {
                    $nin: [
                        "ACCEPTED",
                        "DELIVERED",
                        "VIEWED",
                        "VISITED"
                    ]
                }
            },
            then: "SENT",
            else: "$members.$[e1].email_status.$[e2].prevalent_status"
        }
    }
}
},
{
"arrayFilters": [
    {
        "e1._id": memberID
    },
    {
        "e2._id": email_statusID
    }
]
})
```